Should I use 'road' or 'road transportation'?
I checked a few dictionaries. None of them says road can mean a mode of transportation. So, do I have to use road transportation instead of simply using road?

Road (transportation) was the primary mode of transportation.



"By road was the primary mode of transportation" is the "correct" way to render that sentence, but the sentence is structurally off-putting. I would suggest restructuring to something simple like "Goods were primarily transported by road."

While we're considering that nuance,  we might as well bring up another.  I don't think commodities carried in liquid form by pipeline would be considered "goods". Merriam-Webster offers a BrE definition of the plural noun goods ( "freight" ) and in AmE "goods" are distinguished from commodities like crude oil and petroleum.

I assume the background for this question is that you have this graph, and want to talk about its data using full sentences. The first thing to notice is that the words on the graph are not sentences, just labels. Also, we have the same problem with most of the other labels. "The shipping method is rail" is understandable, but "The shipping method is by rail" is better.

Reader understanding is the most important consideration, and context always matters. If you are explaining how goods reach buyers, and you have a list like this, it would be fine to say "road" for example:
Mode of transport:
Road
Rail
Air
Water
In my opinion, those terms would be understood to mean "by conveyances that operate on these transport pathways" -- in other words, cars and trucks on roads, trains on rails, airplanes in air, and boats and barges on water. This is considering the context, and that readers know the subject is commerce and modes of transportation. The terms "by road" and "by rail" are well understood in that context, in my opinion. You can always check a few similar reports or academic papers for appropriate terminology.
Ultimately, the choice of terms can depend on the surrounding introductory and explanatory information. If you have already mentioned "modes of transportation" then the word "road" has additional context and makes sense. If you are starting from a blank slate, then you probably need to make clear that you are discussing "transport by roadway" and also explain that the category includes trucks, cars, etc. -- or however you define it.

Not an answer in keeping with  technical usage.

There is:
transportation by road, by rail. Try that, you'll see.
There is also, when contrasting, transportation by sea or by land or by air or by rail.
Bear in mind that many international organizations use transport for trade terms.
BUT:

In the world of trade, the company with the ability to transport
freight in the most cost and time efficient manner reigns supreme in
their industry. Therefore; an essential part of transportation
management lies in building an efficient supply chain from the six
main modes of transportation: road, maritime, air, rail, intermodal,
and pipeline. Understanding the strengths and weaknesses of each mode
is paramount to building an effective supply chain.
6 modes of transportation

The author has several paragraphs on each and uses an attributive noun as an adjective: Road Transportation, Rail Transportation
Why? Because for intermodal, transportation BY intermodal, doesn't work even though it works for all the others, except maritime which becomes transportation by sea.
By the way, there is also transportation by river or lake.

You could consider the following:
Road transportation was the primary mode.
Road was the primary mode for transportation.
This enables us to avoid repeating transportation.
